# Redirect user download request to a completely different server

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, get, webserver

Let's say I want to store user files on GCP, but my website is hosted on AWS.

Would it be possible when user visits `https://www.example.com/some_file` to start a download that exists at GCP?

How would that be accomplished? Through a Express route in my NodeJS app?

Would the original url be retained?

What's the best option here?

Answer (score 2):

Just redirect them with the appropriate status code and `Location` header...

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://gcp.example.com/somewhere-else
```

If you're using express, a convenient method exists:

```
res.redirect(301, 'https://gcp.example.com/somewhere-else')
```